# Blank page, no design showing

Tags: php, html, pdo

I'm still new at coding so please be gentle.
I can't seem to get any of this to show on a webpage. Not even the design.

```
function listing_count($category){
global $conn;

    $sql = ("SELECT count(*) FROM listing WHERE int_category = :int_category");
    $stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute(array(
    ":int_category" => $category
    ));
    $category = $stm->fetch();

    if(empty($category['0']))
    {
        $category['0'] = 0;
    }

    return $category[0];
}

<? 
    foreach ($category as $row)
    {
?>
        <li class='list-group-item'>
        <a href='categories.php?cat=<?=$row["cat_id"]?>'>
        <?=$row ["cat_name"] ?>
        <span style='padding:5px;'>
            <?= listing_count($row["cat_id"]) ?>
        </span>
        </a>
        <span style='font-size:20px;' class='pull-right'>
            <a href='category.php?cat=<?=$row["cat_id"]?>' rel='tooltip' class='tooltips' data-original-title='View category'>
            <i style='margin:5px; color:green;' class='icon-eye-open'></i>
            </a>
            <a href='?deletecat=<?=$row["cat_id"]?>' onclick='return makesure();' rel='tooltip' class='tooltips' data-original-title='Delete category' >
            <i style='margin:5px; color:red;' class='icon-exclamation-sign'></i>
            </a>
        </span>
    </li>
<?
    }

 ?>  

    </ul>
```

So this is what I get when I echo category,row and listing_count:

Category: Array
Listing Count: 0
Row: (Row never displayed anything.)

Comment: if you use print_r($category) - what's the output?

Comment: Do you really not find this as incorrect syntax ? `} <? 
`

Comment: If I do print_r i get this: Array ( )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some suggestions for debugging:

- Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of the script to force error output
- Turn `<?` into `<?php` (depending on settings, this is usually required with recent PHP versions)
- Turn `<?=` into `<?php echo` (same reason as above)
- Put `;` after each of your inline php lines.

Comment: This is good advice, but it isn't an answer to the question and should really be a comment, or part of a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: This was very good advise. The error reporting helped tremendously. And I have now fixed it. I had a capital C in category when I shoudlnt have. I hate those small mistakes that mess everything up. Thanks so much for you help.

Answer (score -2):

I bet that `$sql = ("SELECT count(*) FROM listing WHERE int_category = :int_category");`causing syntax in mysql queries
I think if you use ``  (back tick) to wrap around the term after int_category =  then it should returns some row results

For example, `"select count(*) from listing where int_category =`backtich your_term`;`

Comment: __Do not__ back tick PDO named parameters.